# how to use ui-select in ui-grid displayed in a modal

Tags: angularjs

I have used Brian Hamm's code (http://brianhann.com/ui-grid-and-dropdowns/) to display successfully a ui-select in a ui-grid. I am now using the same code but the ui-grid is being displayed in a modal window..and you guessed it...the ui-select does not work..the ui-select-match field does not display in the cell and the dropdown does not drop down.

I cannot find anything on this topic in stackoverflow, github or elsewhere, but this cannot be a unique issue. I would imagine many applications want to use uigrids in a modal that have ui-selects.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using ui-bootstrap?  If so, I would suggest checking it out.  Also, make sure that the modal scope contains the data needed to populate ui-grid.

Comment: i am so embarrassed...i had put the call to get the data for the dropdown in the wrong place. I put it in the controller for the modal..it was only being called after creation of the ui-grid...having said that I was doing something I had done when creating a modal without a ui-grid where it works.  There is no tick for me for accept your answer..i have no idea why not.